# Azure devops ASP.Net Core EF migration production connection string null

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build my ASP.Net Core using a build pipeline in Azure devops and get an error when running a script to script the ef migration.

I do not have the production connection string in the appsettings.json file on purpose. The production connection string populated in the Configuration section of the app service. I know the web application can connect to the database as I have published using Visual Studio and tables have been created in the production database and also can read/save to/from the DB.

the script I'm running is:

```
dotnet ef migrations script -i -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\scripts.sql --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyApp\MyApp.csproj --startup-project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyApp\MyApp.csproj
```

The error in the script output is:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   connectionString

So the question I have is how can I pass the production connection string to the ef migrations command without having the connection string in the appsettings.json file?

Comment: change the environment by `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production`, and then the  `dotnet ef migrations` command will handle it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps can't access your WebApp configuration out of the box. You could read them with a custom script using the [Azure API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings)'s, but I don't recommend that, since that API also could get other Information about your Azure Setup.

I recommend that you move the configuration (or the shared part of it) to an Azure Key Vault, then you can easily use the configuration from both [.NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [Azure DevOps](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureKeyVaultV1/README.md).

Afterwards when Azure DevOps has your configured ConnectionString in it's Environment, the usual `dotnet ef migrations` command should work.